# How to replicate Azure sql db in cross subscription

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is there any way we want to replicate sql db in other subscription

1. To copy data from one subscription
   to another subscription
2. The job should do incremental copy daily.

Answer (score 0):

I do have bigger questions around why you'd want to do it across subscriptions. That aside, you could automate things via Azure Automation and Runbooks:

1. Export SQL DB to BACPAC from subscription 1 and save it to storage account in subscription 2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)
2. Import BACPAC file in to sql server in subscription 2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import)

Another option to look in to would be Azure Data Factory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). I'm especially fond of the Azure-SSIS integration in Azure Data Factory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Data sync might be a good solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data

I've only used to to sync between azure and on premise SQL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

But here is a PowerShell example configures Data Sync (Preview) to sync between multiple Azure SQL databases:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-sync-data-between-sql-databases